# Regex number generator for certain time range?

Tags: regex, algorithm

I'm trying to get a regex number generator for a range of 9 a.m to 9 p.m.

I've tried this (9|1[0-9]|2[01]) but this is 9 to 21 (which is 9pm military time). The solution I have may be the answer but I didn't know if there was another way to generate 9 a.m to 9 p.m. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean that you need to **validate** 9 a.m. to 9 p.m.? Regex is not a "generator".

Comment: You should consider providing sample data which passes and sample data which fails. Show examples with or without minutes and meridiems.

Comment: is `9:01 p.m.` valid or does it stop at `8:59 p.m.`?

Comment: Are you just trying to validate that the hour is between 9 and 21?

Comment: 9: 01 p.m is valid @MonkeyZeus

Comment: I'm trying to validate 9 am to 9 pm. @JimMischel

Comment: So you need to validate optional minutes as well? Are `8 p.m.`, `8:00 p.m.`, `8pm` valid?

Comment: yes @MonkeyZeus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work:

```
/^(((9|10|11)(:[0-5][\d])? ?[aA]\.?)|((12|[1-9])(:[0-5][\d])? ?[pP]\.?))[mM]\.?$/gm
```

https://regex101.com/r/CuDoq9/5

Results:

```
9 a.m.          // match
8 a.m.
11 a.m.         // match
11 a.m. garbage
9 p.m.          // match
12 a.m.
12 p.m.         // match
12 p.m. garbage
8 p.m.          // match
8:00 p.m.       // match
8pm             // match
9:45 pm         // match
9:45 PM         // match
9:45 P.M.       // match
```

Comment: Something to note here is that in some regex flavors (.NET and Python3, for example), `\d` matches any digit from any character set. It's the same as `\p{Nd}`. In others, like Javascript, `\d` is the same thing as '[0-9]`.